# Fixed top div not working

Tags: html, css

OK so I'm trying to make a top fixed menu and I have this CSS:

```
#top {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #000, 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px #000, 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px #000, 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 0;
    }
```

As you can see I have width: 100% but when loading the page the top div is a little crooked to the right, not fully width. I took a screenshot available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQwBK.png). I tested in Opera 11 and Google Chrome.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `width: 100%` with `left: 0; right: 0`.

Alternatively, you can keep `width: 100%`, but then you'll need to remove the default `margin` on `body`:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I chose to remove the default margin on body.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it has no margins and set`left` to`0` so that ignores the paddings of the`body`DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

You might have padding / margin at the BODY (it has margin as default)
Also check if there is no padding / margin inheritance in the css that affects your element

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the code you provided. However is your #top div inside another div? if so make sure that there is no padding in that div. I recommend that you use Firefox with FireBug as it's the best tool for debugging html, css and javascript.